# Lanzar script en bash con dialog para ver usuarios que pertenecen a un grupo en samba-ad-dc

Tags: dialog

La idea es usando dialog con la opción de --menu generar un script para ver los usuarios de un determinado grupo de un dominio de samba-ad-dc. En el caso de ser un grupo de nombre simple como por ejemplo: admin2, funciona correctamente, el problema viene cuando cuando se ejecuta con un nombre compuesto como por ejemplo: Domain Admins.

El comando correcto es: # samba-tool group listmembers Domain\ Admins

Cuando se genera con el script, en la ejecución del comando al añadir con echo la barra inclinada a la izquierda para marcar el espacio en  el terminal, el comando ejecutado aparece de la siguiente manera.

samba-tool group listmembers 'Domain' Admins

Con lo que el comando es erróneo y no da la respuesta deseada. Dejo el código reducido:

########################################################################################

```
#!/bin/bash -x
grupo=$(dialog --title "Samba groups menu" --stdout --menu "selec" 0 0 0 \
Domain\ Admins "" \
)
echo ${grupo}
samba-tool group listmembers ${grupo}
var0=$(echo "${grupo// /'\ '}")
sleep 5
samba-tool group listmembers $var0
sleep 5
members=$(samba-tool group listmembers $var0)
(dialog --title "Members of $var0" --msgbox "${members}" 0 0)
exit
```

#########################################################################################

¿Como se puede evitar las comillas simple con echo?

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es sencilla: hay que escribir la variable entre comillas dobles para interpretar la variable. Funciona en terminal y usando dialog.

```
#!/bin/bash -x


grupo=$(dialog --title "Ejemplo de menu" --stdout --menu "Opciones" 0 0 0 \
Domain\ Admins "" \
Domain\ Computers "" \
)

samba-tool group listmembers "${grupo}"

sleep 4

members=$(samba-tool group listmembers "${grupo}")
(dialog --title "Members of ${grupo}" --msgbox "$members" 0 0)

exit
```